# Ubuntu Samba Server Problems

Tags: samba

I'm currently setting up a samba server on an old school computer for my photo class but I tried to setup samba and it didn't allow me to install the necessary things to get samba rioting. I was wondering if I could make a live cd of ubuntu server with all of the proper things installed so I can install it and just start creating users.

Comment: Please add the steps you took and the error messages you got to the question, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: If this turnkey thing works I won't need to but I won't be able to post them until tomorrow anyways. :/

Answer (score 2):

Making a live CD is a possibility. Have you tried the turnkey Linux live distro that includes Samba? More than you need, but it's here: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller

Edit: to address the adding of users, here's the really short version: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2072

There's more configuration to do in setting up the shares if you want to share more than home directories. A more in depth discussion is here: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/17948-samba-configuration-cant-configure-smb-conf.html

Essentially the workflow is: create Linux user, add to smbusers, if you want more shares than home directories configure them.

Comment: This actually looks perfect for what I need! Thanks you! I'll have to try this out when I get home on a virtual machine so I can figure it out then I'll install it on the computer at school If I like it.

Comment: Alright I just setup a turnkey domain controller on a virtual machine and I am trying to figure out how to setup users and everything. If I get this working correctly I will probably use this!

Comment: added some links and an overview of the workflow

Comment: Thanks for the links! I got the users to work and now for some reason I can't login. I was able to log into the original administrator account the was made. I am making progress though!

Comment: details on can't log in...to the linux or the windows host?